# What is imprecise column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Creating index on computed column of type `nvarchar` raises following error:

> Cannot create index or statistics 'MyIndex' on table 'MyTable' because
>   the computed column 'MyColumn' is imprecise and not persisted.
>   Consider removing column from index or statistics key or marking
>   computed column persisted.

What does **imprecise** column mean?

UPDATE. The definition is following:

```
alter table dbo.MyTable
    add [MyColumn] as dbo.MyDeterministicClrFunction(MyOtherColumn)
go  
create index MyIndex on dbo.MyTable(MyColumn)
go
```

UPDATE2. The `MyDeterministicClrFunction` is defined as following:

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString MyDeterministicClrFunction(SqlString input)
{
    return input;
}
```

Comment: What formula are you trying to use for the computed column value?

Comment: Is it `nvarchar(xx)` or `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: `MyOtherColumn` other column is `nvarchar(50)`.

Comment: OK, so step 1 is to add `PERSISTED` to your `ALTER TABLE` statement

Comment: I do not want to persist that column, I want to make it precise:)

Comment: @TN. that's nice, but if you want to index it it needs to be persisted.

Comment: Why? This works ok: `alter table dbo.Entities add [State] as _LastLogExtra`.

Comment: @TN. See my answer.  There's a special case for CLR functions in indexed computed columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Per MSDN, CLR Function columns must be persisted to be indexed:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

> Any computed column that contains a common language runtime (CLR) expression must be deterministic and marked PERSISTED before the column can be indexed. CLR user-defined type expressions are allowed in computed column definitions. Computed columns whose type is a CLR user-defined type can be indexed as long as the type is comparable. For more information, see CLR User-Defined Types.

Persist the column and I suspect it will work.

Comment: @TN. I think the error message is probably not specific to this case, but a more general message linked to this error.

Answer (score 6):

From the [SQL server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx):

> Any float or real expression is considered imprecise and cannot be a
>   key of an index; a float or real expression can be used in an indexed
>   view but not as a key. This is true also for computed columns. Any
>   function, expression, or user-defined function is considered imprecise
>   if it contains any float or real expressions. This includes logical
>   ones (comparisons).

Comment: @TN - could be because it doesn't specify the size of the resulting varchar?

Comment: Or it could be because it's not persisted

Comment: @Eric Petroelje How to specify size in CLR function?

Comment: @TN - I think JNK may be right on this.  There is some more discussion here about imprecise values and CLR functions (and why that requirement exists).  I couldn't quite see exactly how it applies to your situation though... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic=true, IsPrecise=true)]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596101404-02-12.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx

Sounds like the error message is misleading because CLR computed columns have to be persisted anyway (to be indexed).

Comment: +1 Thx, but it gives slightly better error message: `Cannot create index or statistics 'MyIndex' on table 'MyTable' because SQL Server cannot verify that key column 'MyColumn' is precise and deterministic. Consider removing column from index or statistics key, marking computed column persisted, or using non-CLR-derived column in key.`