# Cannot create index ... imprecise, computed and not persisted

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

I can can't create an index on this view

`CCF.UserHistory.NEID` is a calculated and persisted column.

```
CREATE VIEW [Calais].[vwBossDaily]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Score, 0))               AS Score,
         SUM(ISNULL(DivideBy, 0))            AS DivideBy,
         COUNT_BIG(*)                        AS Count,
         ReportDefGroupID,
         ImportDate,
         MetricID,
         ISNULL(Calais.Card.BossNEID, 0)     AS BossNEID,
         ISNULL(CCF.UserHistory.BossNEID, 0) AS BossBossNEID
  FROM   Calais.Card
         INNER JOIN CCF.UserHistory
           ON Calais.Card.BossNEID = CCF.UserHistory.NEID
              AND Calais.Card.ImportDate = CCF.UserHistory.keyDate
  GROUP  BY ReportDefGroupID,
            ImportDate,
            MetricID,
            ISNULL(Calais.Card.BossNEID, 0),
            ISNULL(CCF.UserHistory.BossNEID, 0)

GO

/****** Object:  Index [VIX_Card]    Script Date: 10/24/2013 11:28:01 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [VIX_Card]
  ON [Calais].[vwBossDaily] ( 
                            [ReportDefGroupID] ASC, 
                            [ImportDate] ASC, 
                            [MetricID] ASC, 
                            [BossNEID] ASC, 
                            [BossBossNEID] ASC )
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
        ONLINE = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Error:

> Msg 1901, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Cannot create index or statistics 'VIX_Card' on view 'Calais.vwBossDaily' because key
>   column 'BossBossNEID' is imprecise, computed and not persisted.
>   Consider removing reference to column in view index or statistics key
>   or changing column to be precise. If column is computed in base
>   table consider marking it PERSISTED there.

A simpler repro of the issue is

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
id int,
BossNEID AS CAST(id as float) PERSISTED
)

GO

CREATE VIEW V
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ISNULL(BossNEID, 0) AS BossNEID
FROM dbo.T  
GROUP BY ISNULL(BossNEID, 0)

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON V(BossNEID) /*Fails*/
```

Comment: You say *CCF.UserHistory.NEID is a calculated and persisted column.* but the error message is complaining about `BossBossNEID`. Not `NEID`

Comment: Both are Calculated persisted

Comment: I've set up a simple repro and see the same thing. Took the liberty of adding it to your post to give answerers something to play around with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is imprecise column in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484036/what-is-imprecise-column-in-sql-server) The answer by @Eric has details about float columns considered imprecise.

Comment: @ypercube - Not sure I agree. The accepted answer there says "Per MSDN, CLR Function columns must be persisted to be indexed:" they have persisted it and still can't use it in an indexed view. Also changing the persisted column definition to `BossNEID AS ISNULL(CAST(id as float), 0)  PERSISTED` still doesn't allow it to be indexed when used in a `GROUP BY` giving `The view contains a convert that is imprecise or non-deterministic.`

Comment: This behaviour is by design. You can't use imprecise data types as keys directly or in expression.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, the accepted answer does not really answer the question ("What is imprecise column in SQL Server?"). I can retract my close vote here.

Comment: @RomanSergeev - `CREATE TABLE T(id int,BossNEID AS CAST(id as float) PERSISTED); CREATE VIEW V WITH SCHEMABINDING AS SELECT BossNEID FROM dbo.T;CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON V(BossNEID)` succeeds. But as soon as you add `GROUP BY BossNEID` it fails.

Comment: What is an "imprecise" field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Persistence* is not the issue here. **Preciseness** is.

From [Create Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx):

*Even if an expression is deterministic, if it contains float expressions, the exact result may depend on the processor architecture or version of microcode. To ensure data integrity, such expressions can participate only as nonkey columns of indexed views. Deterministic expressions that do not contain float expressions are called **precise**. Only precise deterministic expressions can participate in key columns and in WHERE or GROUP BY clauses of indexed views.*

(precise emphasized my me)

Being **imprecise**, is reported as a possible cause of the error.

As I understand it, two floating point values may differ by such a little amount, relative to their absolute values, that they may be considered equal by some *processor architectures or versions of microcode* and be considered different by others.